# Выправь или выправи

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно оба варианта: **выправь** и **выправи**

Answer (score 1):

Нейтральной является форма выправь, выправи- книжного стиля.

Answer (score 0):

Если и та и другая формы правильны, так почему "Выправь текст" является ошибкой и так не говорят и не пишут? Как тогда правильно писать? Или выправь вообще не употребляется со словом текст?